# How to ask for Allah's forgiveness for sex before marriage?

Tags: sex

Me and my husband had sex with each other before nikkah and at that time he was my fiancée. What is the correct way to ask for Allah's forgiveness?  Even I know we did wrong, but from day one we knew we were going to marry each other and it was no accident.

Please guide us how to ask for forgiveness and what does the Quran and our Prophet say on this.

Comment: I just wanted to say, you can't know you are going to marry. You may be very intended to do so, but you can never be sure that there won't be any trouble. One's decision may change, one of you may die, etc. This thought of yours is wrong, please try to get rid of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, if some sins happens, you have to conceal it by all means possible, never publicize it. In islam, it is forbidden to publicize our sins (telling you just in case you do not know i already)

Regarding the Forgiveness, the best way to ask for forgivness is Pray tahajjud (last 3rd portion of night) and cry infront of Allah.

You can recite this:

> رَبَّنََآ إنَّنَآ ءَاَمنَّا فَاغْفِرْ لَنَا ذُنُوبَنَا وَ قِنَا
>   عَذَابَ النَّارِ
>
> Rabbana innanā amanna, faghfir lana, dhunoobana wa-qinna
>   'adhāāban-naar (Our Lord!  we have indeed believed: forgive us, then,
>   our sins, and save us from the agony of the Fire) [surah Ali' Imran;
>   3:16]

Another hadith states that ask for forgiveness in this way:

> اللَّهُمَّ أَنْتَ رَبِّى ، لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ أَنْتَ ، خَلَقْتَنِى
>   وَأَنَا عَبْدُكَ ، وَأَنَا عَلَى عَهْدِكَ وَوَعْدِكَ مَا اسْتَطَعْتُ ،
>   أَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنْ شَرِّ مَا صَنَعْتُ ، أَبُوءُ لَكَ بِنِعْمَتِكَ
>   عَلَىَّ وَأَبُوءُ بِذَنْبِى ، فَاغْفِرْ لِى ، فَإِنَّهُ لاَ يَغْفِرُ
>   الذُّنُوبَ إِلاَّ أَنْتَ

The best time that duas are never rejected are

- at time of rain
- during travel
- between iqamat and jamat standing for prayer

So ask Allah for forgiveness specially in those times too.

Best is to do supplications of morning and evening, here is link to them: 
http://ittibaa.com/uploads/2/8/2/1/2821629/morning_and_evening_supplication.pdf

These supplications a best way to ask for forgiveness of Allah. so make them a habit (both of you) do the morning supplications after Fajr prayer, and do the evening, after asr prayer

May Allah forgive all of our sins

Comment: Interesting! Can you give me reference for your first sentence?

Comment: @zed111 : here is reference : http://islamqa.info/en/3365

Comment: @hamza islam, Isn't Tahajjud also one of the best time that duas are never rejected? and thanks for the information "First of all, if some sins happens, you have to conceal it by all means possible, never publicize it. In islam, it is forbidden to publicize our sins "..I also didn't know the last line..

Comment: yes, tahajjud is also bet time. but the times i gave above are proven from hadith,that dua in those times is never rejected. which is different from tahajjud.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to best times to ask for forgiveness in other answer:

http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/93 : Abu Dharr said: "The Messenger of Allah said to me: 'Have Taqwa of Allah wherever you are, and follow an evil deed with a good one to wipe it out, and treat the people with good behavior."

Answer (score 0):

what if your sins are known by some people but through other sources , I regret what i did a lot but some people know about it . Can I be forgiven ?